# How to plot several regression lines in same scatter plot in R?

Tags: r, plot, regression

I have a dataframe with data of **body temperature (Tb), substrate temperature (Ts)** for several individuals of **both sexes** and comming from **three different populations** like this:
(I made up this table since I couldn't manage to share my full table, but I have around 30 individuals from each pop)

```
pop  sex  tb  ts
bo    m     37   30
bo    m     39   29
bo    f     36   36
pa    m     40   34
pa    f     37   28
pa    m     37   33
pa    f     36   26
re    f     35   24
re    f     37   29
re    m     38   30
```

I want to assess the relationship between Tb and Ts but not only for the species but for each population separately in order to identify possible differences in slopes among them.

```
my.regression <- lm(tb ~ ts*pop*sex, data = mydata)
```

I managed to plot a scatter plot with different colors, one byeach of my populations. However, I couldn't plot my regressions lines. I searched for answers everywhere: about how to add the regression lines by group...(not in stackoverflow, not even with the help of almighty google, youtube tutorials, R book, R graphics books and so on)

All I want is to plot one regression line by each population. Something similar to [image: this plot]

Comment: First advice: keep reading [**the tutorial**](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/) someone suggested in your previous plot question and work through the examples. It will make your walk on the `ggplot` path so much smoother. For the current question, see e.g. [**here**](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Scatterplots_%28ggplot2%29/#set-colorshape-by-another-variable). Perhaps `facet`ing by sex?

Comment: @Henrik: thanks for the idea of faceting by sex, I added it to my answer

Comment: Thanks for the edition (where can I learn how to paste the tables properly??). Happily I'm in continuous learning since I enter this website. I've been reading ggplot material but I keep facing coding troubles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easy to do using [ggplot2](http://ggplot2.org/) and a [geom_smooth](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_smooth.html) layer:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mydata, aes(x=tb, y=ts, col=pop)) + geom_point() +
            geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE)
```

If you want to separate by sex as well, then as suggested by @Henrik you might want to try placing them in separate subgraphs (called facets):

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(tb, ts, col=pop)) + geom_point() +
             geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE) + facet_wrap(~ sex)
```

Alternatively you could plot by both of them, but use the line type (solid or dashed) to distinguish sex:

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(tb, ts, col=pop, lty=sex)) + geom_point() +
             geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE)
```

Comment: The firs option helped me very much. However, there is something strange with that plot. It turns that it doesn't plot all the values. I realized that when I specified "shape=pop" and I saw that for one of the populations, it only plotted three points when I know I have at least 30 measurements on that population. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Could you please post the result of `dput(mydata)` so I can reproduce it?

Comment: I found it out. It turns that several points are overlapped and that's why it looks like they're less than they actually are.
Do you know any way to move them slightly to the right to make them all appear in the plot?
I know how to do it when use the function "plot" but I'm very new to ggplot2. Thanks!

Comment: @Maria: what do you mean by "move them slightly to the right"? If you move them all by the same amount they'll still all overlap. However, you can move them all by a small, random amount (what we call jitter) which will make them visible: you can do this by replacing `geom_point` with `geom_jitter`. See [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_jitter.html) for more, including how you can adjust the amount of jitter you add.